# How to change a specific button, without using the `this` command in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, voting-system

Right now my website's voting system is working, except for the fact that when i like something, it'll change the color of the button (via the this.* commands in the jquery/javascript file),

but then when i click on the opposing button [the dislike button] it'll color the dislike button and keep the like button colored, `effectively having both buttons colored until i refresh the page`...

How can i grab the button element that is next to the clicked element?

So far my js code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".vote", function (event) {

        var clicked = $(this);

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        event.preventDefault();


        request.done(function (data) {
            if (data['vote'] == 1 || data['vote'] == -1)
            {
                clicked.children("button").attr('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-sm');
            }
            else if (data['vote'] == 0)
            {
                clicked.children("button").attr('class', 'btn btn-default btn-sm');
            }
        });

        request.fail(function (data) {
            alert("Voting failed!");
        });
    });
});
```

and my view code [multiple instances of these as there are multiple boxes with a like/dislike pair of buttons.]:

```
<!-- Like button -->
<a style="text-decoration: none" class="vote" href="<?php base_url(); ?>vote/like/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="font-size: 3em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    </button>
</a>

<!-- Dislike button -->
<a style="text-decoration: none" class="vote" href="<?php base_url(); ?>vote/dislike/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="font-size: 3em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
    </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a div around each pair of vote buttons

```
<div>
    <!-- Like button -->
    <a style="text-decoration: none" class="vote" href="<?php base_url(); ?>vote/like/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            <span style="font-size: 3em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        </button>
    </a>

    <!-- Dislike button -->
    <a style="text-decoration: none" class="vote" href="<?php base_url(); ?>vote/dislike/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            <span style="font-size: 3em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Then modify the request done call to uncolor both buttons before coloring the clicked button.

```
request.done(function (data) {

    clicked.parent().find('button').attr('class','btn btn-default btn-sm');

    if (data['vote'] == 1 || data['vote'] == -1)
    {
        clicked.children("button").attr('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-sm');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i shouldve made my question more specific. [i have multiple instances of these pair of buttons as there are multiple boxes with a like/disliks buttons.] So if i did the above, it would uncolor every single button on the page

Comment: Works as it uncolors it, but it still uncolors every single button on the page, regardless of a div wrap.

EDIT: Works, i see you changed it from `.parents('div')` to `.parent()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the vote button which is not clicked like this:

```
var clicked = $(this);
//get reference to the non-clicked vote button
var otherVoteButton = clicked.siblings(".vote");
//do something with the other vote button
```

Comment: Sorry, i shouldve made my question more specific. [i have multiple instances of these pair of buttons as there are multiple boxes with a like/disliks buttons.]